# Is there a way to export jar from IntelliJ Idea so that it works in JMeter?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, jar, jmeter

I'm making a custom JMeter sampler and while exporting `jar` files works fine in Eclipse, I can't figure it out in Idea.

I know there's a similar, but not quite the same question about exporting jars from Idea like in Eclipse. Its solution doesn't work for me. The resulting `jar` is way too big (20MB vs 7KB) and JMeter doesn't launch properly when trying to load it. Aside from that, I need to add a `Main` method to any class in a package/project that I am exporting so that it counts as an "artifact" in Idea, which is an unnecessary step for my goal.

This makes me think that there should not be an easy way to export `jar` from Idea, like there is in Eclipse for JMeter plugin development purposes. Is that true? Or is there a way to do it?

Comment: If you have made changes in idea then to build it (appropriate package where you have made the change) and copy that file jar from build/ dir to jmeter's /lib/extras/ dir. Restarting JMeter should show changes.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're referring to. I'm talking about the fact that the whole "artifact" is turning out too big. I could not make it work like in Eclipse so far. The resulting jars don't open in JMeter.

Comment: If you have made changes in core package of jmeter then using ant builder, you can build that project. After successful building you can copy that core jar into path mentioned in above comment. it should work

Comment: I don't want to edit jmeter code, I'm only interested making an external plugins implementing sampler interfaces.